# How can I dynamically achieve a multiple image layering effect?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here's a picture of what I want to do:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQO2r.png]

where all the pictures are different and I could have between 2-10.

The code I have now is:

(flag is # of pictures)

(picUris[] is my array of Uri's)

```
RelativeLayout imgLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutPictures);
        for (int i = 0; i < flag; i++)
        {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageURI(picUris[i]);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lp.setMargins(50*i, 50*i, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

            imgLayout.addView(iv, lp);
        }
```

and the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYD7x.jpg]

The problems are that it's getting resized and doesn't get cut off by the screen like I want, and there's something weird going on at the bottom.

Comment: nothing changed :/

Comment: That's what I did in: lp.setMargins(50*i, 50*i, 0, 0); where 0<=i<5, and you can see it in the pic above, there are 5 photos at margins of 0,50,100,150,200. The problem is that they are getting resized to fit on the right and bottom edges and not going off like they need to. Sorry if it wasn't clear in the pic, I haven't tried adding anything yet like a border  around and shadow behind the photos

Comment: I believe it's the `RelativeLayout` doing the resizing. `RelativeLayout` does a lot of manipulating of its child `View`s to get things laid out in a way that it "thinks" is right. You might try using a `FrameLayout` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [Stackview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html)? basically it will achieve the exact smae result without making you creating the view progrimatically....you don't have to re-invent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

> where all the pictures are different and I could have between 2-10

I think you should use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) and offsetting each layer by for example [setLayerInset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). Or creating all of the background in `xml` and set it to your `viewgroup`. I do not recommend you use `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` because they both use much `RAM` in your situation.